# SQL Server Dependencies

Tags: sql-server

Is there an easy way to chase down table/stored procedure/function dependencies in SQL Server 2005+?  I've inherited a giant application with lots of tables and even more stored procedures and functions that are long and interlinked.

At the end of the day is there a way to build a dependency tree?  Ideally what I'm looking for goes in both directions:

**For a table/procedure - what depends ON it?**:  Show me all the stored procedures that eventually reference it (ideally in a tree view such that sub procedures nest out to the bigger procedures that call them)

**For a procedure - what does IT depend on?**:  Show me all the procedures and tables that a given procedure will (or could) touch when running.

It seems this tool shouldn't be that hard to make and would be incredibly useful for DB maintenance generally.  Is anyone aware of such a thing?  If this doesn't exist, why the heck not?

The built-in functionality in Management Studio is nice but the information does not appear to be complete at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Red Gate has a pretty useful tool called [SQL Dependency Tracker](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Dependency_Tracker/index.htm). We've successfully used it for the type of results you're wishing to obtain.

Comment: Finally got around to using the free trial - this is a great tool.

Answer (score 27):

Hopefully I'm not too late with this:

If your SQL Login has access to the sys schema in a particular database, you can use the sys.dependencies view to find all of an object's dependencies in one shot:

```
SELECT o.name, o.type_desc, p.name, p.type_desc
FROM sys.sql_dependencies d
INNER JOIN sys.objects o
    ON d.object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects p
    ON d.referenced_major_id = p.object_id
```

Using this as a starting point you could probably build a decent tool to create a dependency tree.  There are also type specific views (e.g. sys.columns) that give more in depth information regarding each specific database object type; these could be used to provide contextual information on an object if necessary.

Comment: I believe the Object Catalog views that the `sys.objects` table belongs to was introduced in SQL 2005, but a similar query can be written using the Information Schema views.  They are a little bit trickier, but you can find documentation on them at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933204(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: You can save this to Excel and import using [Gephi](http://gephi.org) (a free and really advanced Graph visualizer)

Comment: BTW `sql_dependencies` is deprecated now so better use `sys.sql_expression_dependencies`

Answer (score 3):

I have found this solution and its great.

```
SELECT referencing_schema_name, referencing_entity_name,
referencing_id, referencing_class_desc, is_caller_dependent
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('dbo.udf_func', 'OBJECT');
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a guaranteed-complete list, but in Management Studio you can right click on a table or stored procedure and choose the `View Dependencies` option.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of options if you're low on the budget:

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1294

You could also run a trace and see what management studio is actually doing when you click 'view dependencies'.  Grab that code and see if you can modify it for your own use.  This is a good technique for figuring out how to automate various things that you normally do through the UI.

Comment: Using profiler you should be able to see what code is running against the server.

Answer (score 0):

The system table that attempt to keep track of dependencies is usually wrong, so any answer you get from that, you will have to re-confirm by other means, so why bother with it?

Commercial products exist, such as Redgate SQL Dependency Tracker.

A poor developer like myself, I use SQL Digger, which is free.  By searching the DDL for an object name, you usually can find what first degree dependencies there are for an object in question.

The next level of dependency tracing is to trace what C# or VB.NET net objects depend on an object in SQL, but AFAIK, tools don't exist for that outside of global search.

Answer (score 0):

try this productivity tool http://sqlhopper.weebly.com/
It's cool

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190624.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies
WHERE referenced_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Production.Product');
```

We can make it fancier:

```
select
I.name depending, I.xtype dependingtype,
E.name depended, E.xtype dependedtype
from sys.sql_expression_dependencies D
left outer join sysobjects I on D.referencing_id = I.id
left outer join sysobjects E on D.referenced_id = E.id
where 1 = 1
and ( E.name = 'mytable' or I.name = 'mytable' )  -- customize this any way you want
order by dependedtype, depended, dependingtype, depending
```