# List of stored procedure which using another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

We have almost 2100+ stored procedure in database. we are not able to check each stored procedure to find out whether it is using another stored procedure or not.

Any query to find out same?

Thanks,

Dhruval Shah

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/finding-dependencies-in-sql-server-2005/277

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sql Server Dependencies](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299128/sql-server-dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't have dynamic SQL code, you can get the dependencies from SQL Server.

[This article](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1294) explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the free [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search) tool from Red Gate