# How to tell if a SQL Server Table is used anywhere

Tags: sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sql Server Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299128/sql-server-dependencies)

I have a database I need to trim down in order to copy it to a cloud development platform with space limitations.

**What is the simplest way to determine if a table has any dependencies on it?**  For example needed by sprocs, foreign key dependencies, etc.

I understand outside queries could always happen, but that's not a concern.

I could just start deleting things and see what breaks, but that takes some testing time and could easily miss something.

Comment: @Cade: It's close, Jeremy S has what I would a call a good solution, but I think the query could be modified for this question to be optimal.  Question is for the simplest way, and I'm not sure that is the simplest.

Comment: Can you explain what would make it more "optimal"? Why does it need to be simpler than 6 lines you copy and paste?

Comment: @Lee Whitney - That question I flagged as duplicate was for an "easy" way and yours is for the "simplest" way.  I'm not sure what's easier or simpler than picking a method putting it in a proc and doing `EXEC ShowDependencies 'tablename'`

Comment: Aaron, I'd explain it, but it looks like 5 people couldn't even wait 5 minutes for a clarification before closing this as a duplicate.  I don't see any benefit to them doing that so fast but whatever.  For your part thanks for asking before acting.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - A button he can press that is entitled "Do What I Want".  Preferrably in a fruit flavour.

Comment: @Lee Whitney I'm sorry that there is something which differentiates your question from that other one.  There are several reasons to close quickly because it directs people to improve the other question instead of splitting effort over two questions.  I agree it isn't perfect and could probably be improved.  If your requirements are significantly different, please feel free to post another question.

Comment: @Cade Roux, thank you for your professional and polite constructive answer.

Comment: @MatBailie, I have two suggestions for you:  1) Kiss ass.  2) Or instead what I hope you'll choose, is to consider that this approach doesn't doesn't build up the SO community. it just makes it more like the rest of the Internet.  For argument sake, let's assume every question/comment I've ever made here is stupid and  worthless.  If so, I would apologize for that, and assure you that at minimum every question I ask I will attempt in good faith, with careful thinking before posting (however capable that is), and an attempt at civility and respect for anyone else here trying to do the same.

Answer (score 8):

Try right clicking the table and View Dependencies