# Quick way to find usages of DB Objects in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Just like Alt F1 gives you information about any DB object.,  Is there any quick way to find out at what all places is a particular db object refered to. 
For instance:

```
-A table used in other stored procs. 
-A stored proc used in other stored procs. 
-A user defined type used as table value parameter in stored procs.
```

and so on...

In the past i have used Red Gate SQL Search but i will have to take permission here at my company to install it.

Queries will do too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299128/sql-server-dependencies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dependencies information is a lot more robust in 2008 than previous versions as you no longer get permanently missing dependency info when creating objects in the "wrong" order.

[Stealing the example from Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630351.aspx)

```
SELECT referencing_schema_name, 
       referencing_entity_name, 
       referencing_id, 
       referencing_class_desc, 
       is_caller_dependent
FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities ('Production.Product', 'OBJECT');
```

Comment: does not really work. I tried putting  a table name and sproc name in the function call.

Comment: What both at the same time? It doesn't support that.

Comment: No. not at the same time, used it individually ('procname', 'object') ('tablename','object')

Answer (score 1):

It's free, use Red-Gate SQL Search http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on an object in SQL Server Management Studio, there's a 'View Dependencies' feature.

What's the difficulty in getting SQL Search installed on your company machines?

Comment: I couldnt discover anything like View Dependencies on right click. Are you 100% sure that this was from SSMS?

Comment: Yes, it's on the right click menu for a table. Which version of SSMS are you using?