# Is there a way to know which objects are actually being used in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I found here [Quick way to find usages of DB Objects in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7341127/quick-way-to-find-usages-of-db-objects-in-sql-server-2008) a few ways I can check dependencies of objects in a SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

But is there a way to know if an object is actually being used? In other words, I see that a stored procedure uses a certain table, but how to I know if that stored procedure is ever executed, and if so, by who?

I'm asking because I came to a place in which there are A BUNCH of stored procedures and tables, and nobody knows what is being used.

Comment: It's a great idea, but I'm asking because I came to a place in which there are A BUNCH of stored procedures and tables, and nobody knows what is being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tables, you can use [index statistics](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/spring-cleaning-your-indexes-part-i/):

```
SELECT  getdate() AS RunTime 
,       DB_NAME(i.database_id) as DatabaseName
,       OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id, i.database_id) as ObjectName
,       *
FROM    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS i
WHERE   object_id > 100
```

This works for all tables because SQL Server keeps index stats even for heaps.

Stored procedures are harder.  You could instrument them, like:

```
create table SPCalls (name sysname);
go
alter procedure dbo.YourSP
as
insert  SPCalls ('YourSP');
....
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. I don't understand the piece you did for SPs. Do you mean to add a line of code to every SP i have to create a log?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Takes a bit of work.  Might help to script all stored procedures by right clicking the database, then Tasks, then Generate Script.

Comment: Yup my comment into an answer. About the only other way I can think of is, is set up Profiler, to log to a file and then mine it, but I suspect trying to get what you want out of it would take longer than adding a log line to each sp.