# Stored procedure dependencies in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I don't know much about the MS world, but now it happens to be that I have to use SQL Server Management Studio 2008.

My problem: I have a column in a table, and I need to see all the stored procedures that may be acting on it.

I tried right-clicking and going 'View Dependencies' but that doesn't seem to be returning everything that it should be.

Questions like this one: [SQL Server Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299128/sql-server-dependencies) have answers that offer 3 types of solutions

1. Paid third party tools.
2. Writing your own scripts.
3. Exporting everything into text files and grepping them.

WTF? Am I missing something obvious? Is that actually how things work? I would imagine that this is a very common use case: you want to alter table and you want to make sure you won't break anything. Or if say you're looking at a new project with a DB for the first time and you want to see how certain columns get populated with stored procedures. Is there actually no quick and easy built-in workflow to do this?

Comment: Yes, the options are correct.  What if a stored proc is using dynamic sql - it wouldn't really be identified as a dependency unless the tool just looked for the column name in all the text of a proc, which would lead to false positives etc

Comment: Ok, thanks. This is unforunate, I feel that something would be better than nothing.

Comment: You also may need to update to resolve missing dependencies: See here - http://activ8nz.com/Blog/professional/post/2010/11/01/resolving-missing-dependencies-in-sql-server.aspx

Comment: I've blogged about this as well : https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the links guys. I did not realize that all this seemingly simple stuff has so many pitfalls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you need to find database objects (e.g. tables, columns, triggers) by name - have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??

Comment: SQL Search is GREAT - one of the best ways to quickly find all references to something in your DB +1 from me!

Comment: Thanks, this will solve my problem. I'm still amazed that microsoft didn't just include this functionality in their product.

Comment: @suslik: lucky us that there are third-party tool vendors like Red-Gate who fill those "holes" - and if it's for free, it's even better! :-)

Comment: @marc_s The funny thing is I'm in a corp environment without admin rights for my machine. I actually need to file a ticket to have this software installed, and it takes days!

Answer (score 1):

Use this query:

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%YOUR COLUMN %' 
AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have spent a good amount of time trying to find a way to identify column level dependencies in a quick way without having to search text or use third party applications.  The other challenge is finding dependencies across multiple databases where table names may repeat, which will cause false positives when searching SP text.

As of SQL 2008, there is a function that returns dependencies across databases on a field level.

The code below works with a few exceptions:

- It will fail if there are stored procedures with invalid references on tables/fields that have been deleted (Incidently I found this to be useful to find SPs that had been accidentally broken by table modifications).
- It doesn't find all dependencies in cases where the SP is using temp tables in unusual ways.
- In some cases I found that it was returning false positives for complex stored procedures.

[MSDN Documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630351%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

This code should be run from within the database where the SP is in order to be able to cross to other database dependencies.

```
SELECT      
--SP, View, or Function
ReferencingName = o.name,
ReferencingType = o.type_desc,

--Referenced Field
ref.referenced_database_name, --will be null if the DB is not explicitly called out
ref.referenced_schema_name, --will be null or blank if the DB is not explicitly called out
ref.referenced_entity_name,
ref.referenced_minor_name

FROM sys.objects AS o 
cross apply sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.' + o.name, 'Object') ref
where o.type in ('FN','IF','V','P','TF')
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you cannot see the dependencies via the 'View Dependencies' dialog because it works perfectly fine for me. Nevertheless you can query the 'sys.sql_expression_dependencies' system view and obtain the dependency information that you want.

Example

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id),OBJECT_NAME(referenced_id)  
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies 
WHERE referenced_id = OBJECT_ID('XXX')
```

You can of course project other information that you might need.

Comment: This is not what `View Dependencies` does.

Comment: @David - This is what msdn says about 'View Dependencies' - 
*The Object Dependencies (General Page) for the current object lists both the database objects that must be present for the object to function properly and the objects that depend upon the selected object.*
msdn further suggests to query the view that I mentioned http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345449(SQL.105).aspx

Comment: That is what it should do, but it doesn't track them. If any dynamic SQL is used, it won't track them. If anything is changed after the original compilation of a procedure, it won't change. The view does not show anything that the dialog doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

List of All Dependent Objects in single query.

select distinct A.name from sys.procedures A inner join sys.sql_dependencies B
on A.object_id = B.object_id;

OR

select distinct A.name from sys.objects A inner join sys.sql_dependencies B
on A.object_id = B.object_id where A.type_desc = 'mentioned your Object Type';