# Need to identify if a T-SQL query I run is modifying any records without access to logs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to modify a stored procedure that has a long chain of stored procedures within it. I'm not sure what parts of this proc will cause updates to live tables though. What I want to do is maintain all of the tempdbs it creates and select from them, but prevent any record changes via update, insert, delete, etc. Ideally I want to be able to see this info from directly inside SSMS without DBA level permissions. I'm running this on a test DB, so it would also be appropriate if something could tell me what tables were changed after the fact. I could then find the update, prevent it, roll back to a snapshot, then run it again until it shows 0 changes.

I've tried going through by hand and making the changes by searching for keywords like Update, Into, and Exec. However, this involves a lot of human judgment and adds a lot of room for human error. I've also considering wrapping this in a begin..rollback transaction to undo any unintended changes, but this proc can take upwards of 10 minutes to run and I don't want an open transaction that long. I'm also not entirely certain that there *isn't* a commit tran hiding in one of the stored procedures called by this one.

Any help provided would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Throw this into a test environment (like you said it's in, though you are still nervous it seems) and then create some DML triggers, turn on auditing, or run a Trace on your SPID. Since you'll be the only person in the DB, that should be easy.

Comment: And maybe consider downloading Redgate's SQL Search. It's free. It'll search the text of stored procedures, functions, triggers, Agent jobs, what have you, for keywords like `UPDATE` or `INSERT`. All of which can be done by querying system tables, but the tool is dead simple to use. I'm just a fan, not a Redgate shill. :)

Comment: @scsimon I'm wanting to avoid DML triggers because there are so many tables that *could* be updated but aren't necessarily. I'm thinking there are maybe 100ish tables that I could see being reasonably targeted?

As for a trace, is there a way in profiler or extended events to output any table that has it's value changed? I've only ever used it to record when and if a query or proc was ran, but not to analyze the output of those actions.

Comment: @EricBrandt I've used SQL Search at a surface level and have been able to to find those keywords, but I'm worried about the fact that it relies on me catching everything by hand. Without some kind of output that says "You updates x tables", I can't _really_ be sure that I didn't miss anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the stored procedures don't have dynamic SQL and such, you could use the built in utilities to recursively find any referenced tables and stored procedures. This code will show referenced columns and the type of action. I have never used this on a large scale, so definitely spot check as you go.

[MSDN Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/bb630351(v=sql.100))

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.someData
(
    id INT,
    name VARCHAR(100)
)
GO

CREATE  OR ALTER PROC dbo.doSomething
AS
    SELECT name FROM dbo.someData

    UPDATE d 
    SET d.id = 2 
    FROM dbo.someData d
GO

SELECT
    --SP, View, or Function
    ReferencingName = o.name,
    ReferencingType = o.type_desc,

    --Referenced Field
    ref.referenced_database_name,   --will be null if the DB is not explicitly called out
    ref.referenced_schema_name,     --will be null or blank if the DB is not explicitly called out
    ref.referenced_entity_name,
    ref.referenced_minor_name,

    --these will tell you what it's doing
    ref.is_updated,
    ref.is_selected
FROM    
    sys.objects o
CROSS APPLY 
    sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities('dbo.' + o.name, 'Object') ref
WHERE
    o.type IN ('P')
    AND o.name LIKE '%something%'
```

Comment: I like this, very clever solution. It also reminded me that you can see object dependencies by right clicking the stored proc, though it doesn't tell the nature of dependency unfortunately. I'll give it a whirl and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, good luck. Yeah there are limitations, so your mileage may vary. I go into more detail here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/22845865/2088676](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22845865/2088676)

Comment: This ended up being pretty much what I needed. I was able to use the bottom select portion to compare the original proc with the new proc- the new proc doesn't show any rows with is_updated = 1 but the original does. is_update seems to also track inserts, which is nice (I'm on SQL Server 2014 and Is_Inserted isn't added until 2016). Thanks a ton!