# Search ObjectGuid globally in all Relations/Fields

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have to work with an undocumented sqlserver database (10.0.4064) and need to derive the references/foreign keys.

"Show Dependencies" in Management Studio isn't much of a help, it shows only dependencies on views and functions, but doesn't show tables that use the pkey. I suspect the db author didn't use referential integrity at all (maybe for performance reasons).

Anyway, in order to discover the tables references by foreign keys, I need to globally search for an ObjectGuid in all relations and fields. I doubt that this is doable with SQL, but maybe some brilliant mind out there has a workaround for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

This post should do the trick:

[SQL Server Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299128/sql-server-dependencies)

The 2nd answer in that thread would be what you want.

Comment: Thanks. However, that answer only shows the same info that "Show Dependencies" in SSMS shows. And the problem here is, that the dependency hasn't been declared :-/