# SQL Server Refresh Dependencies after Alter Function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqldependency

According to the [ALTER FUNCTION reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186967.aspx):

> Alters an existing Transact-SQL or CLR function that was previously created by executing the CREATE FUNCTION statement, without changing permissions and **without affecting any dependent functions**, stored procedures, or triggers.

I am trying to rename a column, so I found its dependency (UDF) and altered the UDF to not be dependent on that column anymore.

SQL Server 2008, however, did not refresh the dependencies so I still can not rename the column.

Any ideas?  TIA!

Comment: Here is the , 

[Find the Solution here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32858945/1147352

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue was because this is a computed column, and when I ran it as a query (as opposed to via the GUI) I got the following:

> Cannot alter column  because it is 'COMPUTED'.

I dropped it and created a new one with the same formula and a different name.